# Camera gliitches when I walk on hill/slope in Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Good day,

I am making a first-person-view game. That works fine, but whenever I get on a hill/mountain etc. it starts freaking out. The player/camera starts rotating for no reason.

Note: I got some bits of code from external sources, so I don't fully comprehend every bit.

Here is the relevant code:

fpc script:

```
    public float turnSpeed = 4.0f;
    public float moveSpeed = 2.0f;
    public float minTurnAngle = -90.0f;
    public float maxTurnAngle = 90.0f;
    private float rotX;
    void Update()
    {
        MouseAiming();
        KeyboardMovement();
    }
    void MouseAiming()
    {
        // get the mouse inputs
        float y = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * turnSpeed;
        rotX += Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * turnSpeed;
        // clamp the vertical rotation
        rotX = Mathf.Clamp(rotX, minTurnAngle, maxTurnAngle);
        // rotate the camera
        transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(-rotX, transform.eulerAngles.y + y, 0);
    }
    void KeyboardMovement()
    {
        Vector3 dir = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
        dir.x = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        dir.z = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
        transform.Translate(dir * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
    }
```

MouseLookScript:

```
    private PlayerInputActions controls;
    [SerializeField] float mouseSensivity = 15f;
    private float xRotation = 0f;
    private Vector2 mouseLook;
    private Transform playerBody;

    private void Awake()
    {
        playerBody = transform.parent;
        controls = new PlayerInputActions();
        Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        Look();
    }

    private void Look()
    {
        mouseLook = controls.Player.Look.ReadValue<Vector2>();

        float mouseX = mouseLook.x * mouseSensivity * Time.deltaTime;
        float mouseY = mouseLook.y * mouseSensivity * Time.deltaTime;

        xRotation -= mouseY;
        xRotation = Mathf.Clamp(xRotation, -90f, 90f);
        transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(xRotation, 0f, 0f);
        playerBody.Rotate(Vector2.up, mouseX);
    }

    private void OnEnable()
    {
        controls.Enable();
    }

    private void OnDisable()
    {
        controls.Disable();
    }
```

Hopefully someone will be able to help me!

Comment: Is your camera nested under the player? and also which script is attached to which object?

Comment: In general careful when reading the values from https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-eulerAngles.html `Because, there is more than one way to represent any given rotation using Euler angles, the values you read back out may be quite different from the values you assigned. This can cause confusion if you are trying to gradually increment the values to produce animation. `

Comment: This code can't be right.  The camera script should be in its own class file.  You should download a fps demo project from the unity 3d downloads and check out the way its done there.